# CefSharp.Wpf : How can I run that download complete?

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm a new on CefSharp and trying build an application with WPF.

I found the Handler `IDownloadHandler` that handling downloads.

Finally I succeeded to implement downloads, but I don't know that how to launch after downloaded. What should I use for handling download completed?

On MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        var settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings
        {
        };
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
        Cef.Initialize(settings);


        InitializeComponent();


        // I added a download handler
        appBrowser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();

    }
}
```

and DownloadHandler

```
class DownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
{
    public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
    {
        if (!callback.IsDisposed)
        {
            using (callback)
            {

                callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
    {
       // I think I should some codes in here after downloaded, but I cannot sure that.
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DownloadItem` class has properties like `IsComplete`. So you just check `downloadItem.IsComplete` and perform your action then.

Comment: @amaitland Oh, I didn't find that. thank you.